# Regular expression, or condition not working in Swift but works on online debuggers

Tags: regex, swift

I am trying to check if string contains one extra character OR one digit. But for some reason it doesn't work in Swift but it works on online debuggers/editors.

This is my regex: `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[$@$#!%*?&])|(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}`

As I understand then:

```
^ - this is start anchor
(?=.*[a-z]) - string has one character
(?=.*[$@$#!%*?&]) - string has one special character
(?=.*[0-9]) - string has one digit
{6,} - string length is at least 6
```

and in regex validations the regular `|` symbol symbolises `OR` condition.

My question is that why the output is not what I want?

```
stackoverflow - false
stackoverflow1 - true 
stackoverflow@ - false // should be true
stackoverflow1@ - false // should be true
```

This is what I do in swift:

```
func isPasswordValid(_ password : String) -> Bool{
    let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[$@$#!%*?&])|(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}$")
    return passwordTest.evaluate(with: password)
}
```

To be clear, this is what I want: String must be at least 6 characters long and has at least one digit OR extra character. It would be good not to limit the characters to only `(?=.*[$@$#!%*?&])`

Comment: Do you want to match (require) any Unicode letters, digits and symbols/punctuation?

Comment: `.*[a-z]` means "any number of anything, followed by one letter a-z", not "has one character".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think the main set `$@$#!%*?&` for characters is good. And for numbers `0 to 9` is good also.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp No, it is not enough as it does not contain `€`. You say `stackoverflow€` must be true, but how? if it doesn't contain the symbol required. `(?=...)` are positive lookaheads that *require* some pattern to be present in the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ohh, you are absolutely right, but the output is same even if the extra character is for example `@`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you have matches: 1) the start of a string that contains at least 1 lowercase ASCII letter and at least 1 of the special chars inside `[...]`, 2) or matches a string of 6 or more chars that has at least 1 digit.

Also, please pay attention to the fact that `MATCHES` pattern requires the entire string to match, and that is the main reason for your pattern to fail in Swift.

It seems you want to match a string that has 6 or more chars, and should contain at least 1 digit or a special char (I see it can be either punctuation or symbol).

So, you need to use

```
"(?=.*[0-9\\p{S}\\p{P}]).{6,}"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DKjnGY/1). No need for `^` and `$` as the `MATCHES` pattern requires a full string match.

**Pattern details**

- `(?=.*[0-9\\p{S}\\p{P}])` - a positive lookahead that requires that there should be an ASCII digit (`0-9`), punctuation (`\p{P}`) or a symbol (`\p{S}`) after any 0+ chars other than line break chars (prepend the pattern with `(?s)` to allow `.` match line break chars)
- `.{6,}` - any six or more characters.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. And thank you for the more detailed explenation. I was following some tutorial that did explain things a bit wrong. Your solution did work in Playground also, so no need for any aother syntax fixes.